# regular expression like SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, regex

I have a search field form that I use to insert filterexpression on a aspx page.
I would like to force user to insert a string similar to a sql like condition, so it can be:

1. Start or not with %, so %?
2. Write letters, numbers, whitespace, underscore but not a special character like %, so [A-Za-z0-9-_+()\s]+
3. Ends or not with %, so %?$

My reg expression is %?[A-Za-z0-9-_+()\s]+%?$ but it doesn't work because I can write %test%test% that is not a sql like condition.
I have to force writing %test or test% or test or %test% but not %test%test% because the search goes in an error page.
How to do this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't want to take the string and control on code behind if it is in the correct form. I think is more simple to made a regexpress on search form field. But in my regex there is something wrong

Comment: What language are you writing in? ASP.NET includes multiple languages.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were very close, just missing the start of string operator `^`. Without that, you allow a match on your regex on any part of the input, which is why you were able to match things like `%test%test%`. The expression as you had it would just match starting at the second `%`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

public class Program{
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^%?[A-Za-z0-9-_+()\s]+%?$");

        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("%test%"));  //True
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("%test %test%"));  //False
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot the simplest thing...Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I get some explanation for the downvote?